# icon should be right aligned and responsive

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, icons, alignment

i am trying to get a fontawesome icon to be right aligned while a input field on same line shoule be left aligned. both units should be responsive and stay at there positionings.

i created a sandbox and a img where it is wrong to show what i mean.

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-wind-cut7z?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
https://cut7z.csb.app/

[this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBZLN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go **https://jvfe7.csb.app/**

I removed the `w-50` class which made the element only stay at 50% width and I remove the `left: 300%` from the icon. The `flex` property on the **input field** is also overridden by a `flex: none` property and then instead controlled it with the code beneath.

Then I added

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 100%
```

To the element containing both the **input field** and the **icon**. The `justify-content: space-between` makes the two element stay at both the sides, which you want.